# How to set up HADOOP_HOME -CDH5 - vSphere

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, vmware, vsphere

Hello I am running CDH5 and I am trying to load data into HDFS through talend big data and I receive following error:

```
Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries
```

How can I set *HADOOP_HOME* knowing for cdh5 on vSphere if I connect to them remotely? I do not think the *HADOOP_HOME* environment variable is set by default.

Comment: Can you share the code or command that triggers the error?

Comment: [ERROR]: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries. I receive this error when I try to load data from mongodb to HDFS through Talend for big data ,however the file is created in hdfs which means everything is fine with the job , but there is  no data  there ... I need help please read how I am trying to solve it I put some comments bellow

Comment: You need to describe your environment more clearly. I can't understand how you're linking Talend and CDH.

Comment: Hi Guys I wanted to update my question
" I solved one part of it,loading data to HDFS , which I though was related to that error,however the error  is still not fixed and I don't have any clue "
Now I can load data into HDFS through Talend ( @MylesBaker ) to answer your question my environment is the following / I've  built a hadoop cluster one master and three nodes using CDH manager, I am working on a "big data" project 
I use Talend and/or Pentaho as an ETL tool
( I am using both so far,currently I am trying Pentaho)

Comment: I have another problem with it , it does not connect properly to HDFS yet , because I need to load the right cdh5 " shim "  component into Pentaho data integration big data plugin folder ( I currently use pentaho the latest version ) with CDH 5.1
Concerning Talend ,loading data into HDFS was a problem of compatiblity  , the newest CDH version 5.3 which I was using , is not compatible to Talend the latest version , they only can work with CDH 5.1 and the new version will be compatible with CDH5.3 but it is not yet released ,so I switch to CDH5.1

Comment: now let's  come back to the main problem with Talend I still receive the same notification as an error " Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe " and I can't find out how to fix it, though I can see my file in HDFS loaded and complete ..the current version of CDH I am using is CDH5.1  , latest Talend version , and I have my CDH installed in remote servers via Vsphere , my Centos version is 6.6